# bijection and graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Problem:

Let $S$ be the number of simple, undirected graphs with $n$ vertices which does not have vertices with a rank of  $0$.

Let $T$ be the number of simple, undirected graphs that does not have vertex with a rank of $n-1$.

Then $S=T$.

I'm trying to prove this theorem with a bijection but can't think of a one. I'm looking for a simple bijection that solves this problem.

Comment: Something is wrong with the problem statement, since $S$ will be (counting up to graph isomorphism) a finite number (depending on $n$, but bounded by all possible graphs on $n$ vertices), while $T$ as defined would be infinite (since no restriction on number of vertices is postulated).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map that takes the graph $G$ to its [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph). A vertex with degree $d$ in $G$ has degree $n-d-1$ in the complement.